# Copy data from inside KVM virtual machine to host file system

Tags: debian, kvm, qemu

Is possible to copy data from inside of Virtual machine running on `KVM/QEMU` to physical host machine?

Comment: scp is a very simple option.

Comment: How it should work between physical and virtual server on localhost

Comment: If they can ping each other, they can scp. I put a host interface on the bridge that my KVMs are attached to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using folder sharing over virtio (https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup). Although it requires adding run time options for qemu and 9P support to be enabled in your host kernel (Debian kernels have it enabled as modules).